# jQuery $.each for dynamically inserted data not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I have a dynamically inserted `<ul>` and list items using `.html()` in a AJAX call. I want to count the number of list items in the dynamically inserted `<ul>`.

Code:

```
<div id='layout'>
        <a href='javascript:void(0);' class='close'><img src='images/close.png' width='17' /></a>
        <div id='buslayout'></div>
        <div id='boarding'>
            <select name='boarding' id='boarding'>
                <option value=''>Boarding points</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class='seats'><p>Selected seats: <span id='totalseats'></span></p></div>
        <div class='seats'><p>Total: <span id='total'></span></p></div>
        <div class='seats'><p><input type='submit' value='Continue booking' /></p></div>
        <div class='clear'></div>
    </div>
```

jQuery:

`$('#buslayout').html(data);`

```
$('ul li').each(function(){
    price += parseInt($(this).attr('price'));
    console.log($(this).attr('price'));
});
```

Dynamically generated html.

```
<ul>
    <li price='100'>Bus</li>
    <li price='200'>Bus</li>
    <li price='250'>Bus</li>
    <li price='450'>Bus</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: where is the dinamically generated html ;)??

Comment: Where do you define `totalseats`?

Comment: $('.seats').each(function(){... ? or save total seats as $totalseats = jQuery('.seats');

Comment: there is no `price` attribute here

Comment: Are you just inventing the `price` attribute? Not a good idea to use custom HTML attributes and rely on them working... maybe use `data-price`: http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5

Comment: He says "I want to count the number of list items in the dynamically inserted ul", why all the talk about the price attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Count the list items?

```
$('#buslayout').html(data).find('li').length
```

Or, if you want to do it while looping:

```
var liCount = 0;
$('ul li').each(function(){
    price += parseInt($(this).attr('price'));
    console.log($(this).attr('price'));
    liCount ++;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you defined total seats as a jQuery variable?

```
$totalseats = jQuery('.seats');

totalseats.each(function() { ...

**Edit**
Then load the file with $.ajax() and iterate over the returned data

$.ajax({
    url: 'your file',
    success: function(data){
         $.each(data, function(){
             // your func
         });
    }
});
```

Comment: yes, but that didn't happening because the content loaded from the .html() function.

Comment: He wants to count the number of li elements in his ul.